# View Script Output Over SSH?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have a script, called **test.py**, that does the following:

while (1):

....print "hello world"

(this script simply prints 'hello world' continuously).

---

Now, I am using two machines (machine A and machine B). Same user is used for both machines. I would like to do the following:

(1)   **[working with machine A]**   run **test.py** *programatically* on machine A {  meaning, a local python script will be running **test.py** using say os.system(....)  }
       ( at this point, the script **test.py** is printing "hello world" to the screen of machine A )

(2)   **[working with machine B]**   I now want to log in into machine A using ssh and 'view' the output of the script that we ran in (1)

How do I achieve this?  I know how to write the script that will be running and starting **test.py** on machine A. I also know how to ssh from machine B to machine A.

What I don't know is:

(*)    What command should I use in (1) in order to run the python script so that its output can be easily viewed while logging from a different machine (machine B) to machine A?

(*)    Following the ssh from machine B to machine A, how do I 'navigate' to the screen that shows the output of **test.py**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this… But possibly the simplest would be a fifo buffer:

```
A$ mkfifo /tmp/stuff
A$ ./test.py &> /tmp/stuff
```

Then on machine B:

```
B$ ssh A "cat /tmp/stuff"
hello world
hello world
...
```

Normally I would suggest using `screen`, but it assumes that you're going to be running from inside a terminal (which would be tricky). I've heard that `detach` is supposed to be simpler, so possibly you could try that?

Comment: Thank you David. I know 'screen' is used from the terminal. is it possible to use 'screen' from within the python script?

Comment: That… Would probably be tricky. Because `screen` does all sorts of terminal magic to write text in the right place and let you switch between screens and stuff. If a fifo buffer or redirecting to a file isn't good enough, I'd look at using detach before screen.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick alternative is to pipe the output of your python program to a file, and then simply using `tail` with the second user to see the output as it's being written to the file. However, with a program like you have there, the file will *very* quickly become massive.